# Session/Array issue, Shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When an item is added to the cart the item id and the quantity of that item is supposed to be displayed. In this case only the quantity is being parsed from the session. the item ID is not being displayed. Also when a different item is added the cart should display a second item with a separate quantity.

```
<?php 
session_start();


?>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;

    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(1 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    } else {
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $pid) {
                array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1,array(array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                $wasFound = true;
               }
            }
        }
        if ($wasFound == false) {
        array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    }
  }
 }
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}
?>
<?php
$cartOutput = "";
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        $i++;
        $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart item $i</h2>";
        while (list($key, $value) = each ($each_item)) {
            $cartOutput .= "key:$value<br />";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Where/how are you displaying the id?

Answer (score 0):

there's an error in array_splice: arrays are indexed starting from 0.
what's stopping you from using foreach ($arr as $index=>$key) syntax?
and you don't echo $cartOutput at least in that sample.

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $pid = intval($_POST['pid']);

    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1){
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(1 => array("item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => 1));
    } else {
        $found= false;
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $i => $each_item) {
            if ($each_item["item_id"] == $pid) {
                $_SESSION["cart_array"][$i]["quantity"] ++;
                $found = true;
            }
        }
        if (!$found)  {
                $_SESSION["cart_array"][] = array("item_id"=>$pid, "quantity"=>1);
        }
    }
 }
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}
?>
<?php
$cartOutput = "";
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your shopping cart is empty</h2>";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        $i++;
        $cartOutput .= "<h2>Cart item $i</h2>";
        while (list($key, $value) = each ($each_item)) {
            $cartOutput .= "key:$value<br />";
        }
    }
}
echo $cartOutput;
?>
```